# Angular2 Is it possible to get deep nested json value without using ngFor?

Tags: json, angular, get

I am currently getting json object from server and the object also has many nested json object as well. So far, I've been using *ngFor = "let a of data | pipe" (the pipe to get deeply nested value) and single interpolation {{a.value['someValue']}} to get the deep nested value of json object for other situations but this isn't serving my purpose right now since I don't want to loop my json.

Is there any way to get deeply nested json value without using ngFor?

The part of json object I am getting from server.

```
UserProfile: 
{name: 'Jess'
University: 'UC Berkley'
Major: 'Media Communication'
birthday: 1994}

categoryInfo: 
["inish work with quality"]

currentArea
:"CA"

introInfo {
experience: [
0: {Company: 'Atlas', workingYears: 1, **recLetter**:'She was on time always, 
never late. The quality of her work is very high-level.'}
1: {Company: 'Footstep', workingYears: 2, recLetter:'She was on time always, 
never late. The quality of her work is very high-level.'}
]
introduction: "Hello I'm Jess"
}
```

And if I use aforementioned method, it will just loop 4 keys (UserProfile, categoryInfo, currentArea, and introInfo) which I don't want.

How can I get value that's in bold (recLetter) without using *ngFor?

in my component, I am doing this.

```
 userInfo: UserDetailInfo[]; 

  getUserDetail(): void {

    this.userDetail.getUserDetail()
    .subscribe
    (
        userInfo => this.userInfo = userInfo,
        error => this.errorMessage = error
        )
     }
```

And I tried this in the html template but didn't work and I didn't know how to get 'recLetter'

```
{{userInfo.experience['0']}}
```

Please help!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

For the starters, lets assume you get `experience` array always the same, with 2 elements. 
The only thing that you need to do in the html is this:

```
{{ userInfo.experience[0].recLetter }}
```

In case you want to loop through the whole array `exeperience` and display `recLetter` you can do this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of userInfo.experience">
     {{item.recLetter}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**properties.pipe.ts**

```
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'properties'})
export class PropertiesPipe {
  transform(o: {}) {
    return Object.entries(o).map(([key, value]) => ({
      key,
      value
    })); 
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {propertiesPipe} from './properties.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [PropertiesPipe, /* whatever else was here */],
  // ... whatever else was here
}) export class AppModule { }
```

**component.html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="property of userInfo | properties">
    <span *ngIf="!Array.isArray(property.value)">
      {{property.key}}: {{property.value}}
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="Array.isArray(property.value)">
      {{property.key}}: <span *ngFor="value of property.value">{{value}}, </span>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```